# Send HTML based e-mails using wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, email

I'm looking for a code that sends a pre-written, formatted email when a link is clicked (Wordpress)

I tried this:

```
<a href="mailto:YourName@YourSite.com?subject=I love TextFixer.com&body=I learned to create email link code on this website.">YourName@YourSite.com</a>
```

But there are two problems with it

1. It only works if the person clicking the like has an offline email client configured like Outlook or Thunderbird.
2. It doesn't format the email correctly, and doesn't include any links

I was wondering if I can use Contact form 7 with placeholder? Also, will it send the email from single IP address?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18348181/4398840) out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It only works if the clicker have any offline email client configured like Outlook or Thunderbird

Thats how mailto: works. It will open in the default mail client installed in your computer.

> It doesn't format the email correctly an doesn't include links

Try the below code.

```
var emailBody = "1st line.\n 2nd line \n 3rd line <a href='http://yahoo.com'>Yahoo</a>";

emailBody = encodeURIComponent(emailBody);

href = "mailto:me@somesite.com?body=" + emailBody;
```

Set this href variable to the href attribute of your `a` tag

```
document.getElementById("mailme").href = href;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the email templates that contact form 7 sends out in the 'Contact' section of your wp-admin panel. Yes, they will all come from one IP address, that of your server, but unless you're expecting thousands of mails every hour to be sent from it, that's hardly going to be a limitation.